# How do I readjust rows in bootstrap upon window resize?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Basically I have **2** rows of **3** thumbnails. When The screen is sized down (or displayed in tablet computer), I want to have **3** rows of **2** thumbnails, and when the screen is sized down to the minimum (or displayed on a phone) I want **1** thumbnail per row. The third happens on it's own but I can't figure out how to get 3 rows of 2 columns. Visualization:

Desktop (What I have)

[] [] []

[] [] []

Tablet (what I want)

[] []

[] []

[] []

The best I can get

[] []

[]

[] []

[]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if there's even a way to do this in Bootstrap I've been trying for so long.

Comment: Did you place your code in a container? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid past your code in http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: yes, class="container" I just left it out on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the middle row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A row contains col-12, you can chose how you divide the 12,

3x4 =12 = 1 row with 3 elements

4*4 =16 = 1 row with 3 elements and 1 with 1 element

if you go over 12 it goes on a new 'line'.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: This screws up some Jquery animations I had but it fixes the responsiveness issue I had. Thanks!